# Branded Launch Theme with Don't Keep Activities

Tags: android

In my app I use the branded launch theme (the technique explained [in this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd)) for the activity that is launched from the home screen.

The problem is when the user navigate from that activity to another one and the first is killed in background (like when you have `Don’t keep activities` turned on). In that case every time the user press back the activity is recreated and display the "launch" theme, just like when the user tap on the icon in the home screen.

Perhaps this is technically the corrected behavior but it doesn't offer a great user experience. Moreover, is not consistent with configuration changes: in that case when the activity is recreated it seems to be started with the "normal" theme.

*Update*: Digging inside this issue I also tried to "cheat" with the initial theme set when the activity is launched and I found that when `Activity#setTheme` is called the very first time with my "launch" theme the background is already visibile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the answer I got from Ian Lake (@ianhanniballake) on G+:

> 'Don't keep activities' is a developer option for a reason - it isn't
>   something you should be developing around and not representative of a
>   situation users will be in.
>
> I'd use it for testing to make sure you restore state correctly, but
>   that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes the only time your main activity is killed is when the process is killed (ignoring the `Don’t keep activities` case, because that is debug-only, right?).

1. Create a `public static boolean haveShownLaunchTheme` your launcher class, let's call it  `MainActivity`. Default to false;
2. In every Activity in your solution let the first line of `onCreate` be:

   `MainActivity.haveShownLaunchTheme = true;`
3. In `MainActivity.onCreate` modify like illustrated below:

...from:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

...to:

```
if (!haveShownLaunchTheme) {
    haveShownLaunchTheme = true;
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);
}
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Also add the following override of `onDestroy` in order to support re-displaying the launch theme when user is exiting normally through the use of the back button:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy {
    if (isFinishing()) haveShownLaunchTheme = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this exact code but I've successfully used the pattern with global statics to indicate if the process has been killed or not previously.

Comment: Just the Activity is killed, not the entire Application. I've also added a consideration to the question.

Comment: My solution will work even if the MainActivity is killed and not the Application. When the process lives, `haveShownLaunchTheme` will still be true. Whether or not it is an elegant solution is a different question